# 漢字変換を一切しない平仮名/片仮名日本語キーボードをアプリ内に内蔵させたい

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

現在私はiOS/iPadOSアプリを開発を始めたばかりなのですが、そのアプリには平仮名または片仮名のみを出力し漢字変換を一切しないキーボードを内蔵させ必要があります。しかしどのようにプログラミングすればいいのか、いくらググってもキーワードが悪いのか全く事例が見つかりません。
勿論分割してキーボードアプリ単体を別途開発するつもりはありません。そんな物絶対審査を通らないでしょうから。
使用する言語はSwiftUIです。何卒ご回答をお願い致します。

Comment: 「Swift カスタムキーボード」というキーワードで探すと、オリジナルのキーボード作成の情報が見つかりました。やはり「ググ」り方に問題があったようです。それと、「SwiftUI」はフレームワーク名で、言語名ではありませんので、ご注意を。言語名はやはり、Swiftです。

Comment: 審査の話は別として、「キーボードを作ること」自体が目標なのか、「(キーボードを) アプリに内蔵させる」ことが目標なのかが曖昧に見えます。

Comment: XY 問題にしか見えないです。ユーザーが通常使っている日本語変換 IME であなたのアプリに入力した結果がひらがなカタカナ以外を含んでいたら拒絶すればそれでよいのでは？

Comment: おそらくシステムのキーボードに加えて自分のアプリだけで使えるキーボードを表示したいということだと思うので `inputView` プロパティについて調べるのが良いのではないでしょうか。
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621092-inputview

`inputView` に指定したビューにボタンを並べて例えばこのようなこと => https://qiita.com/am10/items/d554f860f9081dc636e7 ができます。

Comment: 私が作りたいのは、漢字検定のアプリです。
システム内蔵の日本語キーボードでは、漢字の読みを問う問題に対し変換候補として漢字を表示させてしまい、ネタバレになってしまって意味を為さなくなります。
従って、オリジナルのキーボードを作ることが目的ではなく、あくまでアプリ内蔵にこだわる必要があります。キーボードが従、アプリが主です。
inputViewについては帰宅後確認します。ありがとうございます。